# what do tableview functions (CellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection) do?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I was viewing some videos on app development with swift, they used these functions but they did not explain about them much. What do they do exactly?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

This function is used in the table view data source to specify how many table view cells you want in the given section. To get this function call (and the other calls), you need to set `tableView.dataSource = self`. Then you can implement this method to set a number of cells in the section.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Use this function to get a `UITableViewCell` and customize the cell for when it is shown in the table. This method will also be called because of the data source property we set. Implement this and return a cell. Here is an example:

```
// This code is off the top of my head, sorry if the syntax or method names are off
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellForReuseIdentifier("ReuseIdentifier", indexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "A title for the cell"
    return cell
}
```